# How to use Amazon DynamoDB to store spatial data?

Tags: java, android, database, algorithm, amazon-web-services

I'm wanting to store & retrieve POIs near some location. Plan to use DynamoDB without any other backend service for the app.

How do I store POIs that can be geospatially searched to give nearest 10 results within 10km radius of some location ?

(I would prefer to accomplish this with DynamoDB as it is fully managed DB service & comes with a 0 initial costs.)

Is there any way to convert latitude/longitude to a set of hashes which can be range searched during retrieval ?

Comment: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash? "First, data indexed by geohash will have all points for a given rectangular area in contiguous slices (the number of slices depends on the precision required and the presence of geohash "fault lines"). This is especially useful in database systems where queries on a single index are much easier or faster than multiple-index queries. Second, this index structure can be used for a quick-and-dirty proximity search - the closest points are often among the closest geohashes."

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Java, AWS have a library for doing this
https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-geo

They also have a series of blog posts explaining how it works
https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxWTJOSLE7O3J2/Geo-Library-for-Amazon-DynamoDB-Part-1-Table-Structure